Does explicitly capturing this by value force a copy of this even if this isn't used in a lambda body?
If I have a lambda in a class member function, and it doesn't actually need to capture this (e.g. it doesn't use any member variables), does explicitly capturing this (by value) force a copy of this?  Or is the compiler smart enough to realize that it doesn't need this and therefore not copy it?
E.g.
class Thing {
 public:
  Thing(int x) : x_(x) {}

  void useThis() {
    int y = [=,*this](int z) { return x_ + z; }(1);
  }

  void noUseThis() {
    int y = [=,*this](int z) { return z + z; }(1);
  }

  void noUseThis2() {
    int y = [=](int z) { return z + z; }(1);
  }

 private:
  int x_;
};

Clearly useThis() will make a copy of this. Clearly noUseThis2() will not make a copy of this.
Will noUseThis() make a copy of this?
I have a code with a lot of lambdas that currently do not explicitly capture this, and I'd like to update them to explicitly capture this.  If they actually use this, they must all capture this by value.  But I'd also like to avoid carefully reading the bodies of all the lambdas to make sure they actually use this -- I can use sed to change all the capture statements but reading them all would be a pain.  But if explicitly capturing this forces the copy, that would be bad in cases where this wasn't actually used.
Edit: ok, so as is often the case, writing out the question made it well posed enough in my head that I could just ask the compiler, and the answer is that yes, noUseThis() does make a copy of this and ignores it.  So to slightly modify my question, does the standard prescribe this, and is there a good reason for it?

Well, give your class a copy constructor that prints something, and see for yourself. My guess is, yes a copy has to be made, because eliding a copy may change observable behavior, and this is not one of the contexts where copy elision is explicitly permitted.

Yeah, see my edit -- that's what I did, and you're right.

BTW, In current snippet y can be computed directly, and with as-if rule, optimizer would probably drop the lambda completely (and method too, as no observable behavior in all that code ;-) ).


Will noUseThis() make a copy of this?

Maybe. Maybe not. According to the standard, there is no difference in the observable behavior of the program, because Thing's copy constructor has no observable effects. Now, if the lambda closure object contains a copy of *this, you would expect the object's size to increase compared to a lambda closure object that doesn't contain a copy of *this, but, from a language lawyer perspective, observing the size doesn't actually prove that a copy of *this was made. The compiler could also have an (admittedly odd) ABI in which it allocates padding that has sufficient size to store a copy of *this, and doesn't actually use the space to store a copy.
Compilers are free to perform, or not perform, optimizations that don't change observable behavior, and they don't have to tell you. This is called the "as-if rule".
In practice, C++ compilers have not yet advanced to the point where they implement optimizations that eliminate unused non-static data members. So you should expect to see an increase in size of the lambda closure object when you explicitly capture *this, but the actual copy operation is likely to be optimized out if it doesn't do anything.

So in the real use case, the copy constructor DOES do something, but that copy would still never be used.  I guess I was hoping that, since the compiler clearly can detect what is needed in a closure (since it can do implicit capture), it could also detect that something explicitly captured (in this case this) was never actually used and therefore could ignore the explicit capture.

Wait, maybe I'm misreading your last sentence.  Do you mean, "but the actual copy operation is likely to be optimized out if it isn't used"?  I mean, even in this case, the copy constructor does something -- it makes a new x.

@EthanCoon The creation of an object by a trivial copy constructor is not observable behaviour. So it can be optimized out. But if the constructor actually has observable behaviour, it can't be optimized out. The standard requires explicit  captures by copy to occur (meaning that their observable effects occur).
